# Comparing int and unsigned int

Tags: c, type-conversion

```
int a = -1;
unsigned int b = 1;

if(a>b)
{
printf("%d>%d",a,b);
}
else if(b>a)
{
printf("%d>%d",b,a);
}
```

So the output of this program says -1 > 1. Am I right in saying that this happens because the (signed) int is converted to unsigned int?

How come it doesn't just converted both to long (signed) int?

Comment: And you expect `long` to have a greater range than `int`? Good luck on POSIX-32